# Custom Options showing price 0.00 in cart

Tags: magento

Im trying to show price for custom option in cart-page but it showing the Product price correctly but the custom price as $0.00 (i.e) if the product price is $50.00 then in the cart page its showing as $50.00 + $0.00 but the actual custom options price is $0.80. Can someone help me with this.
http://www.usbsticks.com.au/stage/checkout/cart/

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution over here it is a issue with Magento 1.7 [here](http://k2xl.com/wordpress/custom-options-broken-in-magento-1-7-heres-the-fix/)

Comment: I don't have any issue in the product page. I have issue in the cart page. I am using Magento 1.3.2.4 version. Anyhow that post doesn't help me by anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file `scpoptions.phtml` from [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/297872/) and place it in:

```
app/design/frontend/default/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/view/
```